# Why doesn't Pandas allow me to use a list to add rows without adding []?

Tags: pandas, list

I am building a dataframe of cleaned data from a text file. My intended dataframe is 11 columns and 2 rows (for now).

```
TestRow1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
columns_headers = [A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K]
```

I thought that this would work:

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data =TestRow1, headers = columns_headers)
```

It doesn't. Instead you get an indices error:

```
error ValueError: Shape of passed values is (11, 1), indices imply (11, 11)
```

However, when I pass this:

```
NewDF = pd.DataFrame(data = [TestRow1], columns = columns_headers)
```

It does work. But why? If you check the type of 'TestRow1' and '[TestRow1]', you find that they are both:

```
<class 'list'>
```

So what's going on here?

Comment: `np.array(TestRow1).shape` yields `(11,)` so basically 11 rows and 1 column `np.array([TestRow1 ]).shape` yields `(1,11)` so 1 row 11 columns.  First one fails because you are assigning 11 columns to an array that only has 1 column.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)

A DataFrame is

> Two-dimensional size-mutable, potentially heterogeneous tabular data structure

So, you either need to pass a 2D array with explicit column names or pass a dictionary as below

```
pd.DataFrame({'column_name': [1,2,3]})
```

**1st case:**

```
new_df = pd.DataFrame(data =TestRow1, headers = columns_headers)
```

This wouldn't work because, there is no named argument `headers`.

**2nd case:**

```
NewDF = pd.DataFrame(data = [TestRow1], columns = columns_headers)
```

This would work because you have converted data into a 2D list aka. `[[1,2,3]]` and also you have provided `columns` with proper argument name.

**PS:**

You are right on the data being `list`. But focus should be on the shape of the list.